# WordPress Multisite (sub-directory based), change subsite URL

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress Multi-site, sub-directory based like this:

https://www.example.com/

I have a site within the multisite

https://www.example.com/site-1/

that I want to rename to

https://www.example.com/site-2/

How would I do this?  I'm assuming besides running a search and replace tool/plugin, I would need to update the URL of that site (i.e., https://www.example.com/site-1/) in the database somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your Network Admin -> Sites menu, you should be able to edit the site and change the site's **Site Address (URL)** to whatever you need it to be.

As for the search/replace: I recommend using [WP-CLI's `search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to do this, if you've got it available.

`wp search-replace https://example.com/site-1/ https://example.com/site-2 --url=https://example.com/site-1 --dry-run` to see what will be replaced, and then run it again without the `--dry-run` argument to actually *do* the search/replace.

Comment: What if you want to move that same site (https://example.com/site-1/) to a new domain (https://newdomain.com), but keep it in the multi-site environment?

Comment: I'd guess that would just work? Does it not?